# Delete logs data after a year with sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, ruby-grape

I'm new in sidekiq and I want to delete data from my model `AdminLog` after a year. I've got a field `created_at` so I'm just thinking if I use method below it will be enough? I think I should initialize it somewhere because how will sidekiq know when to fire it?

```
class AdminLogRemoverWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    expired_logs = AdminLog.where('created_at >= ?', 1.year.ago)
    expired_logs.destroy_all
  end
end
```

EDIT:

I want to sidekiq do it automatically so it should be able to looked for such data every day and be able to delete those data every day.

Comment: https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler will help you schedule this.

Comment: If `AdminLog` has no destroy callbacks or `dependent: :destroy` associations, it would be better to use `delete_all`.

Comment: Thanks @PavelMikhailyuk ! this will be enough for sidekiq to run this worker every day automatically?

Comment: Use Josh's link to schedule every-day job.

Comment: Is there any other method to do so? I cannot use additional gems except sidekiq and sidekiq-cron

Comment: It's not a problem - use `sidekiq-cron` fro scheduling.

Answer (score 2):

What you have will delete all records NEWER than `1.year.ago`, fairly sure you want `created_at < ?` not `>=`.

Also, unless you have some callbacks you need run, you probably want to use `delete_all` rather than `destroy_all` - it'll be much quicker.

### Update

Sorry, forgot the main bit, you'll also want to put some code in there to reschedule this job for the next day ([docs here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs)).  So:

```
def perform
  self.class.perform_at 1.day.from_now.change hour: 1

  #... rest of your stuff
end
```

That's for 1am tomorrow, adjust the hour to whatever suits you.

Comment: Ok but, I want to delete these data automatically after a year. This implementation will be enough for automatically checking data every day? will sidekiq know that he has to do this job every day? shouldn't I implement some kind of loop for that action?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the main bit in :)  Updated.